# Unable to create temporary data extension: Field name cannot be blank error in Salesforce Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

```
SELECT 
ds.Id as [Id],
ds.Discharge_intiated_Date_Time__c as [Discharge Intiated Date Time],
ds.Account__c as [Account__c ],
ds.Opportunity__c as [Opportunity__c ],
op.Appointment_Status__c as [Appointment Status],
ac.Last_Account_Update__c as [Last Account Update],
FROM Discharge_Status__c_Salesforce as ds
INNER JOIN Account_Salesforce ac ON (ds.Account__c  = ac.Id)
INNER JOIN Opportunity_Salesforce op ON (ds.Opportunity__c = op.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an unneeded comma after the last field. Try this:

```
SELECT 
ds.Id,
ds.Discharge_intiated_Date_Time__c,
ds.Account__c,
ds.Opportunity__c,
op.Appointment_Status__c,
ac.Last_Account_Update__c
FROM Discharge_Status__c_Salesforce ds
INNER JOIN Account_Salesforce ac ON (ds.Account__c  = ac.Id)
INNER JOIN Opportunity_Salesforce op ON (ds.Opportunity__c = op.Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to be noted down before executing this query,
if the query is running in SFMC, we do not need semicolon (;) at the end of the query neither in Automation Studio Query Activity nor in the Query Studio (it will give you an error if you add it in your query).
Another thing is the extra comma added before "FROM" clause in your query.

The correct format would be:

```
SELECT 
ds.Id as [Id],
ds.Discharge_intiated_Date_Time__c as [Discharge Intiated Date Time],
ds.Account__c as [Account__c ],
ds.Opportunity__c as [Opportunity__c ],
op.Appointment_Status__c as [Appointment Status],
ac.Last_Account_Update__c as [Last Account Update]
FROM Discharge_Status__c_Salesforce as ds
INNER JOIN Account_Salesforce ac ON (ds.Account__c  = ac.Id)
INNER JOIN Opportunity_Salesforce op ON (ds.Opportunity__c = op.Id)
```